# Jasmine not finding Backbone.js Models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

I've just started using Jasmine with maven. I have Jasmine working, but for some reason it  cannot find my Backbone models. I have the JavaScript src directory pointing to the folder containing my Backbone.js models. In my JavaScript test directory I have a simple test as such:

```
describe('ToDo Model',function()
{
    it('Test',function() {
        var todo = new ToDo();
    });
});
```

But I keep getting ToDo is not defined. Do I have to write my tests inside of the my backbone model files or anything? Thanks.

Comment: Need more information to answer this. How are you defining the ToDo model? Open your specs in a browser and make sure you can't access ToDo in the developer console.

Answer (score 2):

ToDo has to be in the global namespace as well. Try typing this in your Chrome/Firefox console:

window.ToDo

If it returns undefined, then that's the problem!

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a good practice to define a global namespace for your app, for example:

```
window.Application = {
  Models: {},
  Views: {},
  Collections: {}
}

// etc.
```

Then, I like to define models like this:

```
(function (Models) {
  Models.ToDo = Backbone.Models.extend({
    // etc...
  });
})(Application.Models);
```

The namespacing here isn't necessary, but seeing `Models` right at the top of the file is a nice visual cue, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I have my ToDo model inside of it's own file with no real namespace defined, simply var ToDo = Backbone.model.extend... I thought that would put it in the global namespace. When I access the normal page that uses the that model, I can access ToDo off of window.

Comment: Then that sounds like a problem with your Jasmine config.